# Why can't I create a new file in Bridge V2?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I am trying to create an addon for Minecraft and have decided to use bridge V2. As I am new to the software, I decided to watch a few tutorials and all of them show how to create a New File. When I press the New File button nothing happens, whereas all the other buttons work.

Could you explain to me why this isn't working and what the solution is? Thanks.

Edit:
Just noticed after I have attempted to create a new file the tool bar at the top becomes grey and I am unable to click on it which suggest it has done something.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the button not working?

Comment: @pinckerman I have added a screenshot depicting what I clicked which did nothing.

Comment: I asked just for clarity, I've never used that software so no idea..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a tiny button at the bottom right of the page that when clicked on displayed a message declaring that there was a new update and that it needed to reload Bridge. After I accepted and it updated I could create new file without issue. I guess that either there was a bug in the update I was on or it didn't like me being on previous updates. Either way at least it is working now. Thanks to everyone that commented suggestions.